# Adding x=y line to plot containing boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I am trying to overlap a sns boxplot with a line x=y

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[0,2,3,4],[33,12,34]],columns=['1','2','4','6'])
sns.boxplot(data=df)
sns.lineplot(x=df.columns.astype(int), y=df.columns.astype(int))
```

the result is not what I expected 
[image]

as you can see the x=y line does not pass from (1,1) (2,2) (4,4) (6,6).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The line is passing through `(1,1) (2,2) (4,4) (6,6)`... The string ticklabels `1 2 4 6` along your xaxis are actually the x coords `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. What is your desired output?

Comment: IIUC in `lineplot` set `x=np.arange(len(df.columns))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[0,2,3,4],[33,12,34]],columns=['1','2','4','6'])
sns.boxplot(data=df)
sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(len(df.columns)), y=df.columns.astype(int))
```